# What happens in python when I close the windows CMD which was used to run the python script?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have a python program that I run with the Windows CMD. This program has to saved datas when it closes. So, I would know what's happening in python when the CMD is closed by clicking on the red cross button in the top-right corner to be able to saved the datas.

When coding with PyCharm, when a program is running and the stop button pressed, PyCharm raises a "KeyboardInterrupt" exception. So I put something like that in my code :

```py
try:
    ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    save()
```

This works with PyCharm, but not with the CMD. So I coded that :

```py
try:
    ...
except:
    save()
```

This still doesn't work with the CMD.

PS: I'm french and I'm working my english, so if you don't understand everything, I'm sorry about that, tell me and I'll explain better

Comment: It looks like you need to hook into [Windows-specific mechanisms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/closing-the-window) instead of relying on Python-level exceptions. You'd need `ctypes` or an existing Windows API library for that, That's assuming programs run in the terminal have access to the `WM_CLOSE` message.

Comment: Think of the `cmd` window as a virtual environment. Force-closing it (with the "red cross") instantly destroys this environment. It's like pulling the power cord from your computer. It won't do anything anymore from this point. (Besides that, the close button won't generate a keyboard action and why should it - at this point, there exists nothing any more which could process it)